# Merging an array of array with an other array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I got this:

```
first = [['lorem1','lorem1','lorem1',...],['lorem2','lorem2','lorem2',...],...]
second = [value1,value2,value3, ...]
```

I want to do something like that:

```
my_array_of_hash = [{value 1 =>lorem1, value2 => lorem1}, {value1 =>lorem2, value2 => lorem2}, .... ]
```

Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hashes_array = []
first.each do |array|
  hashes_array << Hash[second.zip array]
end
```

or:

```
hashes_array = first.map do |array|
  Hash[second.zip array]
end
```